# How to wait for forEach loop to finish

Tags: reactjs, react-native, foreach, async-await, fetch

I am having an issue where I am trying to fetch data. Unfortunately, when I console log the result, on the initial page load, the data is empty. When I re render the component however, I receive the data successfully.

This is what I currently have:

```
function Followers({
   urlname,
    navigation
}) {
    const [followersData, setfollowersData] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
         // Fetch Followers data
         const dataRef = firestore().collection('usernames')
     
            dataRef.doc(urlname)
            .collection('Following')
            .get()
            .then((docSnapshot) => {
            let items = []

            docSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                let item = {}

                // Store followers, display name and follows info
                dataRef
                .doc(doc.id)
               .get()
                .then((followerDoc) => {
                    const data = followerDoc.data();
                    item.profileName = doc.id
                    item.displayName = data.userName
                    item.followerCount = data.followers
                    item.followingCount = data.following
                })

                items.push(item)
            })
            setfollowersData(items)
            })

    }, [])

return (
    <>
        {console.log('followersData', followersData)}
    </>
)
}

export default Followers
```

The console log I receive on the first page load is:

```
followersData null
followersData [{}, {}, {], {}]
followersData [{}, {}, {], {}]
```

When the component renders again, I receive this in the console log:

```
followersData [all my data in 4 different objects gets logged]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

William's solution is good, but as an option is to wait all the responses and update the state once.

```
const promises = [];

docSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  const promise = dataRef
    .doc(doc.id)
    .get()
    .then((followerDoc) => {
      const data = followerDoc.data()

      return {
        profileName: doc.id,
        displayName: data.userName,
        followerCount: data.followers,
        followingCount: data.following,
      }
    });

   promises.push(promise);
})

Promise.all(promises).then(setfollowersData);
```

Comment: Unfortunately i tried this and received an error: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 2): TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...docSnapshot.map...')   I think you can only use a forEach method here for some reason. Also, could i ask why williams option may not be as good? Thank you

Comment: Oh, I see. So this is a feature of Firestore. It's not an array. Just an object with forEach method. I have updated the code.

Comment: Thank you so much. This also worked, however, the initial state needed to be             
 const [followersData, setfollowersData] = useState() instead of                                      const [followersData, setfollowersData] = useState( [ ] )                                                        Is this more efficient then williams answer? i feel like it is

Comment: This actually depends on your needs and how you are going to perceive this or that value. You can "display" an empty array (display nothing, what William is proposing), or you can display, for instance, loader if value is null or undefined.

Answer (score 1):

call `setfollwersData()` separately for each item using prev state and set initial state empty array.

```
function Followers({
   urlname,
    navigation
}) {
    const [followersData, setfollowersData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
         // Fetch Followers data
         const dataRef = firestore().collection('usernames')
     
            dataRef.doc(urlname)
            .collection('Following')
            .get()
            .then((docSnapshot) => {

            docSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                let item = {}

                // Store followers, display name and follows info
                dataRef
                .doc(doc.id)
               .get()
                .then((followerDoc) => {
                    const data = followerDoc.data();
                    item.profileName = doc.id
                    item.displayName = data.userName
                    item.followerCount = data.followers
                    item.followingCount = data.following
                    setfollowersData(prev => [...prev,item])
                })

            })
        })

    }, [])

return (
    <>
        {console.log('followersData', followersData)}
    </>
)
}

export default Followers
```